# Exclude rows with the same variable in dataframe that have the same value

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to exculde players in this data frame that don't have a difference in points between game A and B.

```
Player  Points  Game
Sam 13  A
Sam 14  A
Sam 15  A
Sam 12  B
Sam 11  B
Sam 10  B
Max 12  A
Max 15  A
Max 13  A
Max 18  B
Max 17  B
Max 16  B
Tom 15  A
Tom 15  A
Tom 15  A
Tom 15  B
Tom 15  B
Tom 15  B
Joe 16  A
Joe 19  A
Joe 15  A
Joe 15  B
Joe 17  B
Joe 12  B
```

I know that I could simply exclude "Tom", but how would I do it in big data frame with hundreds of players without going through each player?

Comment: Even Joe has 15 points in Game A and B. Should that be excluded as well? Please show your expected output.

Comment: @RonakShah Good point, I am guessing players should be matched by row as well, i.e.: Sam row 1 should be compared with Sam row 4, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, one idea would be to find the variance which would be 0 if all values are the same,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Player) %>% 
  mutate(new = var(Points)) %>% 
  filter(new != 0) %>% 
  select(-new)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `uniqueN` from `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`, grouped by 'Player', if the length of the unique number of 'Points' is greater than 1, get the Subset of Data.Table.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(uniqueN(Points)>1) .SD, by  = Player]
```

It is also possible that the OP wants to compare between "Game".  In that case, we subset the 'Points' where 'Game' is 'A' and for 'B', get the difference, check whether all of them are 0, if not, get the Subset of Data.table.

```
setDT(df1)[, if(!all(!(Points[Game=="A"] - Points[Game=="B"]))) .SD, Player]
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Player) %>%
   filter(n_distinct(Points) >1)
```

---

Or a base R option is

```
i1 <- rowSums(table(df1[-3])!=0)==1
subset(df1, !Player %in% names(i1)[i1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using `xtabs` in base R:

```
tb <- xtabs(Points~Game+Player,df)

    # Player
# Game Joe Max Sam Tom
   # A  50  40  42  45
   # B  44  51  33  45

df[df$Player %in% colnames(tb[,diff(tb)!=0]),]
```

The idea is to generate a cross table using `xtabs` for each `Game` and `Player` and then filter out those players for which the difference between the points in game `A` and `B` is not zero (i.e. `tb[,diff(tb)!=0]`)